# How to override the Spark theme in Flex 4?

Tags: css, flex4

What kind of styling is there in the default Spark theme in Flex 4? 
And how to override the Spark theme? For example I want to provide another backgroundcolor and
nothing happens, the color css works as intended. The CSS looks like this:

```
    <fx:Style>
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
    @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
    @namespace local "*";

    global
    {
        font-family: Georgia;
        color: #260B01;
        content-background-color: Red;
        content-background-alpha: 0.8; 

    }
</fx:Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. This code works fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
        global {
            font-family: Georgia;
            color: #260B01;
            content-background-color: Red;
            content-background-alpha: 0.8;
        }
    </fx:Style>
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:List dataProvider="{new ArrayCollection(['First','Second'])}" />
</s:Application>
```

What did you expected and what is your result?

Comment: I used the background-color: property instead and now it works nice.